# Cypress: I have a issues geting a textBox "HELP!"

Tags: dom, css-selectors, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to get a textBox so in the code I added data-cy attribute:

```
<login.StyledInput
        // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-autofocus
          autoFocus={focus}
          type={type}
          value={value}
          disabled={disabled}
          onInput={onInput}
          onKeyUp={onKeyUp}
          data-cy={`${text}-textbox`.replace(/\s+/g, '-')}
        />
```

In the DOM it looks like this:

[image]

This add data-cy in all the textBox, the one I'm looking for is named data-cy=Password-textBox, at the begin, I use this to get it:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=Password-textbox]').eq(1);
```

I'm using `eq(1)` because is the second element with the attribute data-cy=Password-textBox but It didn't work, however, I used the code below and It worked:

cy.get('#other-form-animator > :nth-child(4) > .rs-input-group > [data-cy=Password-textbox]');

the problem is that my boss won't let me use the last one.

Does anyone know of a better-looking solution? and Why  `[data-cy=Password-textbox]` doesn't work?

Comment: Can you try `input[type="password"]` ?

Comment: @AlapanDas this didn't work when I tried to use it with `eq(1)` I got this: [Issue](https://i.ibb.co/gRfVxZB/second.png)

Comment: Can you try without `eq(1)` ?

Comment: Yes @AlapanDas , I did but I think  because there is another  element with input[type="password"] and I get this [issue](https://i.ibb.co/c24wLbK/first-Element.png)

Comment: Its failing on `clear()`. Can you try this `cy.get('input[type="password"]').clear({force: true})` Or if your password field is already empty you can directly type the password `cy.get('input[type="password"]').type(confirmPassword)` OR `cy.get('input[type="password"]').click({force: true}).type(confirmPassword)`

Comment: @AlapanDas `cy.get('input[type="password"]').click({force: true}).type(confirmPassword)` worked, however, the `@` in the password is missing [issue](https://i.ibb.co/x2wxLN8/Screenshot-from-2020-10-21-06-11-57.png)

Comment: Can you try just `click()` instead of `click({force: true})`.

Comment: @AlapanDas click() doen't work and I get this [issue](https://i.ibb.co/cX5Dx82/isuee.png)

Comment: It seems you have to use `{force: true}` with click. Otherwise it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an element by css selector. That selector is a string, this to get a property - You should use [double quotation marks](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Selector) for the property, which is a string within the string. You can literally copy paste it from the element in the inspect menu into this cy.get:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="Password-textbox"]').eq(1);
```